# My member variables are underlined in red in Eclipse

Tags: java, class, object, variables

I am fairly new to Java and OOP and apparently I'm having some difficulty with defining member variables of an object. They are underlined in red and I can't figure out why the error is occurring. I am using the Eclipse 2019 IDE.

I've looked at some other questions and tried to scour some online tutorials but haven't found a solution. I'm fairly certain its not a syntax thing but rather something with the IDE I'm not aware of?

```
public class Main {
    class Person{
        String name;
        int age;
        String hairColour;
        String gender;      
    }

    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();

    person1.name = "Matt";
    person1.age = 26;

    person2.name = "Julie";
    person2.age = 25;
}
```

The errors appear beside the lines where I define the variables for person1 and person2... name and age are underlined in both cases.

Comment: `person1.name = "Matt";` is a statement. It is written on class level. Statements can only be written within methods (same goes for the following three lines).

Comment: Those are not lines where you define variables. They are assignment statements, and they are illegal at class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `person1.name = "Matt";` (expression statement) can't be executed in a class block.

The only statement which can be executed in a class block is declaration statements:

```
Person person1;
//or
Person persion1 = new Person();
```

Expression statements can be run into a method block.

If you want to instantiate your `Person` object with direct values, you can create an parameterized constructor into `Person` class:

```
class Person{

    String name;
    int age;
    String hairColour;
    String gender;

    public Person(String name, int age, String hairColour, String gender){

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.hairColour = hairColour;
        this.gender = gender;

    }

}
```

Now you can create an object Person into a class block, like this:

`Persone p1 = new Person("Batman", 30, "black", "bat");`

I also recommend to read this articles:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_constructors.htm

https://raygun.com/blog/oop-concepts-java/

Answer (score 0):

Objects are created inside methods, but you try to make them in a class. I believe you want to do this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();

    person1.name = "Matt";
    person1.age = 26;

    person2.name = "Julie";
    person2.age = 25;
}
```